# VB.NET dynamically add or remove subreport

Tags: vb.net

I am using VS 2010 - Visual Basic.
I made the main report in Report Viewer:  Report1.rdlc and then 4 other reports (rdlc files too) which I intend to use as subreport at the main report (Report2.rdlc, Report3.rdlc, Report4.rdlc and Report5.rdlc).

The problem I had now is how to dynamically add or remove subreport according to request from the software ?

I know how to determne subreport pathe after I put an object subreport on the rdlc file-right click - subreport properties-"use this report as subreport".
But I must do this from the software becouse sometimes Report3.rdlc must be first subreport or Report4.rdlc. Report2.rdlc will not be every time first subreport.

The second problem I had is how dynamically change the size for rdlc file-Main report (Report1.rdlc):
Sometimes will be only one subreport, sometimes two sometimes 3 and sometimes 4. I do not want to have empty-blank space.

Is this possible to do?

If yes, can somebody put a sample code?

Thank you very much for help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

hi hope this will help you
cos this works for me

```
Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Load the main report definition
    Me.C1WebReport1.Report.ReportDefinition = Me.C1Report1.ReportDefinition

    ' OR you could load it this way:
    ' Me.C1WebReport1.Report = Me.C1Report1

    ' Now insert the subreport.
    Dim f As C1.C1Report.Field = Me.C1WebReport1.Report.Fields("subreportHolder")
    f.Subreport = Me.C1Report2

    ' Set the subreport field's Text property to act as a filter
    f.Text = """CategoryID = "" & CategoryID"

    ' Optionally, hide the subreport header
    f.Subreport.Sections.Header.Visible = False
End Sub
```

you can refer [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1webreport/default.htm?turl=creatingsubreportsdynamically.htm) LInk

Comment: Hi!

Thank you for your code. I tried to put it into my code but I have big problems. OK I am a beginner in programming so maybe this is the reason, sorry... So C1Report.field is not recognised.. I am makin a code for Report Viewer Local  (win form) and the print out on the paper. Anysuggestions regarding that? Thank you in advance.